# Обновить Node Js на Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Установлена версия 14.0.0, в node -v всегда отображается она. Хотя в списке программ Node отображается как 16.13.1.
Я могу вручную менять версию через nvm, но это очень неудобно. Как сделать так, чтобы о версии 14 не было и духу на компе?

Comment: Снести `nvm` и поставить 16.13.1 ...

Comment: да я этот nvm поставил, чтобы была возможность 16ю ноду запускать. Проблема была и до установки нвм